# iOS Back button title is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I have an issue with "back" button in `UINavigationController`

I have a root view controller with method implemented like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NEW BACK" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}
```

Despite of this code, my back button title is still a title of my root view controller instead of "NEW BACK"

Does anyone sees where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hide your default back button then add a button programatically. Add the code in your viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowleft.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 20.0f);
        UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

Add

> btnBackTapped

method anywhere in same class

```
-(void)btnBackTapped:(id)sender 
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NEW BACK" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

in your `RootViewController`, do this in the child view controller means the controller which you are pushing.

Comment: According to Apple, this should be in a root view controller (the one who pushes another one)...

Comment: Can you show me that doc, if you have link. Also give a try my answer

Answer (score -1):

If you set navigation controller's back button, then it will be applied to all the further viewController, though viewController has its own back button configuration. Try to reset the back button in your navigationController. Hope your code will work.